# My big home made batch of Worcestershire sauce is too vinegary

Tags: flavor

I've made this several times before, tweaking a bit as needed. The recipe asks for 2 qts. Apple cider vinegar, and three cups of Orange juice, along with a BUNCH of other ingredients. The vinegar dominates! Sweetness is good, spice and saltiness, good. I've thought of adding another tin of Anchovies, or using an old Spaghetti sauce trick of adding a pinch of baker's chocolate. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to see what your question is here, if it's too vinegary you should reduce the vinegar, which seems obvious. Are you saying you don't want to reduce vinegar for some reason and want to know other ways to balance it out?

Comment: In addition to @GdD’s question; has the recipe *always* come out too vinegary or is this batch different from previous ones. Are you looking to avoid the problem in future or remedy a current batch. Can you post the recipe and method?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm trying to alter this batch, reducing the vinegar is not an option. I failed to mention that I substituted grapefruit juice for the orange juice, as in the last batch the orange taste was evident, and the sauce was too sweet. My first thought is to add another can of anchovies. The recipe comes from "Make the Bread, Buy the Butter". It's far better than anything from the supermarket!